# Java check null faile for result of JSONObject

Tags: java, json

after retrive result of :

```
JSONObject data_array = new JSONObject ( received );
```

i get any `null` for this strings:

```
String c = data_array.getString ( "count_mobile" );
String o = data_array.getString ( "ok" );
String f =data_array.getString ( "faild" );
```

`o` and `f` values are `null` and i can not check it for this codes ( all of incorrect return and set null result to variables )

```
 if( data_array.getString ( "ok" ) != null )
      o = data_array.getString ( "ok" );

 if( data_array.getString ( "ok" ) != "" )
      o = data_array.getString ( "ok" );

 if( ! TextUtils.isEmpty(data_array.getString ( "ok" ) ) )
      o = data_array.getString ( "ok" );
```

Comment: Well what do you expect to happen if `data_array.getString("ok")` *does* return null? You're not setting `o` to anything else. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help here...

Answer (score 0):

use as below

```
JSONObject.NULL.equals(data_array.getString ( "ok" ));
```

Comment: `ok` is `null` and your code is retuen `false` but thats `null` and must be return `true`

Comment: @jJz please post the same code or atleast the json, and what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you only want to the value of a property in the JSON if it's not null, "null" or empty. Try the following code:

```
if (data_array.has("ok")
        && data_array.getString("ok") != null
        && !data_array.getString("ok").trim().equals("")
        && !data_array.getString("ok").equals("null")) {
    o = data_array.getString ( "ok" );
}
```